# How to use React Hooks to refactor existing code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was looking at the React Hooks functions and have some hesitations on how to exactly use useState and useEffect to refactor existing code.

I have, for example, an old-school component like this:

```
class MyFunction extends React.Component{
  state = {
    count1: 0,
    count2: 0
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    return {count1: nextProps.value1, count2: nextProps.value2}
  }

  handleChange1 = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({count1: value});
    this.props.onCount1Change(value);
  }

  handleChange2 = ({target: {value}}) => {
    this.setState({count2: value});
    this.props.onCount2Change(value);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    this.props.someRandomStuffs(this.state.count1, this.state.count2);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.count1} onChange={this.handleChange1} />
        <input type="text" value={this.state.count2} onChange={this.handleChange2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, I cooked up a solution to refactor it like this.

```
function MyFunction(value1, value2, onCount1Change, onCount2Change, someRandomStuffs){
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(value1);
  const [count2, setCount2] = useState(value2);

  useEffect(() => someRandomStuffs(count1, count2));

  function on1Change ({target: {value}}){
    setCount1(value);
    onCount1Change(value);
  }

  function on2Change ({target: {value}}){
    setCount2(value);
    onCount2Change(value);
  }

  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={count1} onChange={on1Change} />
      <input type="text" value={count2} onChange={on2Change} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is the above refactoring close enough? I would like to know if this can be followed to refactor other classes in my project.

Comment: Yup, this does the same thing. Not sure if this refactoring is benefitial at all...

Comment: Note: sometimes refactoring does not mean writing less code or less lines of code.

Comment: Oh no, its not about less codes, my project is far more complex, we are trying to solve problems like unnecessary rerenders, want to divide extract few logic out of some classes and create smaller reusable functions etc

Comment: Plus I want to avoid copy-how-it-was-done-before problem where an implementation gets simply copied by other developers

Comment: Your example looks about right. Separate state variables are used (which is recommended as it offers few benefits) and an effect will run on every update.
Maybe look into providing some guardrails via eslint plugin which enforces [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to be followed (in case you aren't doing that already).

Answer (score 0):

Your converted component would look like this. I think you don't need more `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

```js
const myFunction = (props) => {
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0)
  const [count2, setCount2] = useState(0)

  const handleChange1 = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setCount1(value)
    props.onCount1Change(value)
  }

  const handleChange2 = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setCount2(value)
    props.onCount2Change(value)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    props.someRandomStuffs(count1, count2);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={count1} onChange={handleChange1} />
      <input type="text" value={count2} onChange={handleChange2} />
    </div>
  )
}
```